# Return combination of other delegates

Tags: c#

I need to return expression of multiplication of two other expression, but this example gives me error

```
public Func<double> EvaluateOne()
{
    return () => EvaluateTwo() * EvaluateTwo();
}

public Func<double> EvaluateTwo()
{
    return () => 2;
}
```

in function `EvaluateOne`
error:`can't applay operand * to operands of type Func<double> and Func<double>`

Comment: `return () => EvaluateTwo()() * EvaluateTwo()();`

Comment: omg, looking nice, please copy this into answr and I will accept it.

Comment: @kosnkov What are you trying to accomplish here? This looks like an XY problem.

Comment: If you're writing a parser, you might want to look into ANTLR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use expression trees to do this, which allows you to recursively create an expression of increasing size without computing anything:

```
using NumFunc = System.Func<double>;
using NumExpr = System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<double>>;

...

static NumExpr Square(NumExpr operand)
{
    return Product(operand, operand);
}

static NumExpr Product(NumExpr left, NumExpr right)
{
    return Expression.Lambda<NumFunc>(Expression.Multiply(left.Body, right.Body));
}
```

Now, when you use this, you get nicely formatted logging of the composite expression as a nice bonus:

```
var result1 = Product(() => 2, () => 3);
var result2 = Product(result1, () => 5);
var result3 = Square(result2);

// Nothing has been computed so far!

Console.WriteLine("{0}={1}", result3.Body, result3.Compile().Invoke()); 
// Output: (((2 * 3) * 5) * ((2 * 3) * 5))=900
```

You can see a demo here: http://ideone.com/forcW3

Answer (score 6):

You can't multiply two `Func<decimal>` objects, but you can multiply the results of evaluating them.

```
return () => EvaluateTwo()() * EvaluateTwo()();
```

Answer (score 3):

That is because a call to `EvaluateTwo()` returns a `Func<double>`, not the value 2.

You can fix that by:

```
public Func<double> EvaluateOne()
{
    var eval2 = EvaluateTwo();
    return () => eval2() * eval2();
}
```

**Note:** @Blorgbeard's answer does not have a weakness that the method in this answer has. If a call to `EvaluateTwo()` would return a different `Func<double>`  instance on each invokation, this answer would lead to an incorrect outcome.

Comment: Nice highlight of where second set of `()` comes from using local variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
return () => { double two = EvaluateTwo()(); return two * two; }
```

This way you get both optimization and lazy evaluation.

Comment: That is only the case in this specific example, if `EvaluateTwo()` was e.g. a generator, this would result in an incorrect outcome. That is also the case for my answer by the way.